Change PowerBI Data Source Server without Refreshing Report in PBI Desktop
I have a large number of PowerBI reports where the Source Server and DB is "ServerA.Database1". I have setup data replication so that the tables necessary for reporting are now available in "ServerB.Database1". When I change the Server in PowerBI from ServerA to ServerB and click "Apply Changes", PowerBI Desktop starts a "Load" process that refreshes the data using ServerB as the source.
The problem is this can take 10-20 minutes for large datasets with anywhere from 1-10 queries per report, and I need to do this for 135 reports. I would prefer to just update the Server values, not refresh the data in PowerBI desktop, upload the report with the updated connection to my PowerBI Online Dev instance, then trigger the data refresh in the PowerBI Online Dev instance. That way I don't have to waste time waiting for the Desktop application to reload each query and I can modify the Server of many reports in a short amount of time.
How can I do this? I tried de-selecting the "Include In Report Refresh" option on all of the data tables in the reports, but PBI Desktop still wants to reload the entire report after changing the Server values.
